# XOR operation of 0 with string "hello world" in c

Tags: arrays, c, string

This code gives Segmentation Error can someone help. I've to XOR string "HelloWorld" with 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Hello World";
    int n = strlen(str);
    char y[n];
    
    for (int p=0;p<n;p++) {
      y[p]=str[p]^0;
      printf("%c",y[p]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf(y[p]);` what do you intend that to do? The first arg is a `char` whereas `printf` requires that to be a string. Did you want instead: `printf("%c", y[p]);`?

Comment: if i do %c it print hello world again..but i want the result of xor

Comment: XOR'ing a value with 0 returns the original value. So `y[p]==str[p]` for all `p`, hence you get `Hello World` output from your code after you fix the bug as @kaylum described.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be exactly? If you XOR any value with 0 then you will get the same value back. So the behaviour is correct.

Comment: No...Xor with 0 is not 0 ..please go check how to do XOR first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shouldn’t the char array be n + 1 size to store null character? At least that should be the issue on C, but I think it should be similar on c++

Comment: Hi and welchome to Stack Overflow. Do not try to answer a question with another question. If you need clarification, ask questions in the comment section.